# Timeset - UTC - CAMERAS- TRAVELING - a complete mess

Tags: camera, timezone, gps, utc, photography

I'm an amateur photographer. I have Video, Mobile, Camera, Drone, etc. My goal is to sync all data on the right time and add GPS tag.

I end on configure everything on UTC (except mobile), and add after GPS tag that is on UTC also.

Main problem is how to determine correct timezone based on where the picture has been taken, and if I have to, since all my mobile photos has the timezone (and daylight savings) applied when taking video/photo.

I'm using now an OPEN API for having the correct GMT based on the geolocation and time/date.

Am I doing it right? Am I interpretating DATE/TIME changes correctly? I saw after that Lightroom changes based on the date/time info and the place it's used (photos).

It's a mess.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're asking, but if you have the latitude and longitude of the picture's location, you can look at solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates

Comment: Thanks!. I'm now using this on the background. My main issue is .... I'm the only in the planet that has the same issue?.. Is there any way of doing it better and simpler?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what you are doing based on your description alone.  It would be helpful if you included example data, code, etc., as well as a clear question.  *"Am I doing it right?"* can only solicit an opinionated response, and requires a better understanding of exactly what you are doing.  Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help center.  Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: Well.. I understand it.. but the point is not only the code etc but try to know if there is anyone else that solves the issue better and easier than me. I mostly know how to code it.. but I'm really looking for understanding if I'm missing something here.. since I don't see anyone claiming for a professional software that actually does it (lightroom etc).